# Where does Sound Recorder place the files it records?

Tags: sound, xubuntu

I'm running an LTS version of Xubuntu. I have installed a Sound Recorder and have recorded a test sound. I have restarted the app, to check if this is a permanent recording (and that recording stays, so it is somewhere in the file system).

However, i'm unable to find where Sound Recorder puts the files. I have checked '`~/Music/`' and looked through the directories for something titled '`SoundRecorder`' or '`recorded audio`', but nothing is there.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Ok, I'm unsure how I managed to miss it...

`~/Recordings` is the answer.

Comment: This is also true in Linux Mint Cinnamon 20.3 with Sound Recorder version 3.34

Answer (score 2):

At least in 2022, on my system it stores files in `~/.local/share/org.gnome.SoundRecorder/`, and without any file extension.

Comment: I have switched to Debian from Ubuntu. And i haven't used SoundRecorder in a while, but this is not a very useful directory. Thanks for the update, i am sure others will find it helpful!

Comment: Yes, on my Ubuntu 23.04 it is at ***~/.local/share/org.gnome.SoundRecorder/*** Linux news said an upcoming update would allow user choice.

Answer (score 1):

The **Flatpak** version
`~/.var/app/org.gnome.SoundRecorder/data/org.gnome.SoundRecorder/`

Comment: Ok, i am sorry for you having to find something like this.